# $_Server['REQUEST_URI'] seems to have gone... where?

Tags: php, apache

I had a working system with Apache 2.0 and PHP 5.2.6

I have had to upgrade Apache and PHP, so I now have **Apache 2.2** and **PHP 5.2.12** and for some reason **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** is now missing from the super global in PHP.

This is my test system on my dev PC (not a live server) and there are 4 or vhosts on it.

What config should I check in Apache and PHP to make sure this comes back again, as I need it to work?

Comment: Which OS do you use? Are apache and php built from vanilla code or are some patches integrated? How is php running as apache module/filter or as fcgi?

Comment: A few questions before answering: Linux/Windows? Installed as CGI/Apache Module? Did you use the proper module (`php5apache2_2`)?

Comment: This is on Windows. both are using the vanilla installer downloaded directly and installed. PHP is being used as an apache module using the correct dll (php5apache2_2)

Answer (score 1):

Do the other $_SERVER values show up? If not, check the value of "variables_order" in php.ini. If it doesn't contain "S" then $_SERVER won't be filled.

Comment: Yep, most of them are present. I'm not 100% sure which ones are missing, but this is the only one that was important to my codebase.

Comment: How about `echo getenv('REQUEST_URI');` Does it show up there?